# why my chrome does not cache my JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

Our one page met some performance issue, during the triage,I found our js files are not cached while other resource like img/css are retrieved from cache(in F12 Network tab, in size column, it shows "from memory cache"). 
And in Firefox js files are retrieved from cache,this issue only occurred in chrome.

## Did someone know the reason?Thanks a lot!

I take a js file request/response for example:

**Request Header:**
GET /emsaasui/emcpdfui/libs/1.13.0-161128.193454/js/oraclejet/js/libs/require/require.js HTTP/1.1
Host: slc10uan.us.oracle.com:4443
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: https://slc10uan.us.oracle.com:4443/emsaasui/emcpdfui/builder.html?dashboardId=15
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

**Response Header:**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 07:59:08 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 03:38:36 GMT
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 005GajqWd^qDWb85Rjs1yd0006^80000hX
APIGW: true
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DB-vGDHUkRhI0s2oGq-KN_oGs7ToT7oRrZYsz6eXHsMGBgZCxKQv!1414641782; path=/apigw/resources; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Language: en

Comment: Is your Developer Tools panel open?

Comment: Yes, I opened the Dev Tools(F12) to see if cache worked, but it didn't. I checked the header(including Cache-Control: max-age=2592000..etc.), it is okay for me, is that possible that web server(like apache) may cause this issue?